# How i change paragraph text when button clicked from streamlit.components.v1 using python function

Tags: python, streamlit

```
import streamlit as st
import streamlit.components.v1 as components

def my_fun():
    #change paragraph text when button clicked
    pass
a="""
<div>
<button id="my_btn">Click Me!</button>
<p id='my_para'>Hello word<p>
</div>
"""
components.html(a,height=800,width=1200)
```

i am trying to change paragraph text from python function when button press from streamlit.components.v1

Comment: You've tagged this a Java question -- please explain the Java relevance.

Comment: i am sorry i edited question and removed java.